# Writing to a instance variables to a text file

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

I need to take a list of Objects and write their instance variables to a text file. It would look something like this:

```
Hot Dog,1.25,Grocery Store
Gas,42.15,Gas Station
etc.
```

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public void writeListToFile(String fileName, ArrayList<BudgetItem> writeList) throws Exception {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<writeList.size(); i++) {   
        if(writeList.get(i) instanceof Expense) {
            Expense writeExpense = (Expense) writeList.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
                dump(out, writeExpense);
            }
            finally {
            }
        }
        else if(writeList.get(i) instanceof Income) {
            Income writeIncome = (Income) writeList.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
                dump(out, writeIncome);
            }
            finally {
            }
        }
    }
    out.close();
}

public void dump(PrintWriter out, Expense writeExpense) {
    out.print(writeExpense.getDateOfTransaction().get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getDateOfTransaction().get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getDateOfTransaction().get(GregorianCalendar.DATE));
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getItemName());
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getMethodOfPay());
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getPlaceOfPurchase());
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getQuantity());
    out.print(",");
    out.print(writeExpense.getPrice());
    out.print("\n");
}

and one other method similar to the 2nd one.
```

When I run it, it only writes out one line, the first object in the list, and nothing else. I can't figure out what's going on. I know object serialization is a faster option, but for this project, since I am still learning, I want to use this way.

Main method as requested by one of the answers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String itemName = "Hot Dog";
    int quantity = 1;
    String placeOfPurchase = "Weiner Stand";
    String methodOfPay = "Credit";
    BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(1.25);
    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar(2013,11,1);
    Expense e = new Expense(g, price, itemName, quantity, placeOfPurchase, methodOfPay);
    BudgetItem bi = (BudgetItem) e;
    String itemName2 = "Gun";
    int quantity2 = 1;
    String placeOfPurchase2 = "Weiner Stand";
    String methodOfPay2 = "Credit";
    BigDecimal price2 = new BigDecimal(1.25);
    GregorianCalendar g2 = new GregorianCalendar(2013,11,1);
    Expense e2 = new Expense(g, price, itemName, quantity, placeOfPurchase, methodOfPay);
    BudgetItem bi2 = (BudgetItem) e2;
    ArrayList<BudgetItem> abi = new ArrayList<BudgetItem>();
    abi.add(bi);
    abi.add(bi2);
    RegisterFileIO rfio = new RegisterFileIO();
    rfio.writeListToFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data.out", abi);


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data.out"));
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(in);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(lineScanner.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but I think the problem is that you create a new `PrintWriter` for each item in the list. Try to create the `PrintWriter` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: Why not put the responsibility for creating the output on the `toString()` method of each type?  Then you only need to do `System.out.println(writeExpense);` once for each object.

Comment: Which line does it print out? The first in the loop or the last expected in the loop?

Comment: It is only printing the first in the loop.

Comment: Are you sure? Try `System.out.println(writeList.get(writeList.size() - 1);`. See what it prints out. I have a feeling its printing out the last and not the first. I may be wrong but if I'm right, I think I know the problem.

Comment: So right now I only have 2 items in the list. Writing that out returns this:
mod5.Expense@93dcd
mod5.Expense@93dcd

mod5 is the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you creating a new `PrintWriter` each iteration. You should declare it outside the loop. What is happened is that when a new `PrintWriter` is created it overwrites the previous data stored in the file.

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    for(int i = 0; i<writeList.size(); i++) {   
        if(writeList.get(i) instanceof Expense) {
            Expense writeExpense = (Expense) writeList.get(i);

            dump(out, writeExpense);
    }
 } finally {
 }
```

Comment: okay that fixes the problem somewhat. It's now writing the same object everytime, and it is not writing each new one on a new line even though I print a newline character at the end of the dump method. Maybe a carriage return as well?

Comment: 1) You need to use `println()`, instead of `print("\n");` and 2) It's more than likely you objects in your array are referencing the same object. You wanna show the code where you populate the list?

Comment: You're using e twice `BudgetItem bi = (BudgetItem) e;`

Comment: Do that for all you BudgetItems. What you're doing is referencing the same BudgetItem e

Comment: Or maybe you want to just change the second (BudgetItem)e to (BudgetItem)e1. You're using the same (BudgetItem)e for both

Comment: funnily, changing it didnt help. I changed e to e2. That should have fixed it.

Comment: It's still printing the same object?

Comment: That's because you have the same info for both of them Hahaha, Silly

Comment: And even if you change the data, you're instantiating both `Expense`s with the same variables.

Comment: Except for itemName2 which is "Gun", whereas itemName1 is "HotDog". That is how I can differentiate, but it's returning "HotDog" both times

Comment: Oh, but look at you're instantiation of the second `Expense`. You're using the same variables as in the first. Your missing the `2`s at the end of the variables

Comment: LOL haha thanks I wouldn't have noticed otherwise. I feel silly for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're instantiating a new `PrintWriter` object (and a new `FileWriter` object) for each object in your list.

You should instantiate it only once, before the `for` loop. Replace

```
PrintWriter out = null;
```

with

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
```

Just a side note: with your current code, you might end up with a `NullPointerException` at line `out.close();` if your `ArrayList` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First: you are writing java, not C++.  Use Java structures and techniques.

As mentioned by MadConan, your implementation is overkill.  Use toString() (or toBlammy() - blammy being something other than string) on each object type (Expense and Income) to format the output.

Hint: anytime you have a bunch of `if (instanceof blammy)` you should consider polymorphism instead.

You code should look something like this:

```
public void writeListToFile(
    final String fileName,
    final List<BudgetItem> listBudgetItem)
throws Exception
{
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try
    {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        for(BudgetItem current : listBudgetItem)
        {
            out.println(current.toBlammy());
        }
    }
    catch (... exceptions)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        // close the PrintWriter.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do appreciate that you would take time to look at my stuff, but what I will say is, I am a student trying to learn. As I'm working through this project I'm learning all kinds of things, including polymorphism, serialization, etc. Even though I've learned these, I have a deadline to meet and not nearly the time to go back and change my whole program. I do not appreciate the context in which you put your suggestion.